# How do you create a daemon like application to receive information from a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

The goal is for my main application to either launch or be told when a usb device is inserted.

To achieve this, I created a windows service and a shared remote object.  I have a little windows forms application that runs in the background to launch the application.

Its the little windows forms application I'm struggling with.  How can I get it to start automatically and stay running throughout the user session?  It seems to me I'm asking for a lot of bugs with this design.

This little intermediate application simply does this:

```
channel = new TcpChannel(55555);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(SharedRemoteObject.RemoteObject), "USBDetectServer", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
```

That's all this thing does.  What is stopping me from putting this in the service itself, rather than have this intermediate program running?

If I can't put it in the service, does anyone have suggestions about how you can have a little, GUI-less application running throughout the user session that is not a service?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx